# ImportError: No module named msg

Tags: ros, custom-message, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have googled a lot of solutions, but none have worked.
I follow exactly the same as http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_msg.
Is there anything I missed?

my python script

```
import rospy
import cv2
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
from face_detection.msg import TwoPoints
```

The error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/tlkoo/catkin_ws/src/face_detection/src/face_detection.py", line 10, in <module>
    from face_detection.msg import TwoPoints   File "/home/tlkoo/catkin_ws/src/face_detection/src/face_detection.py", line 10, in <module>
    from face_detection.msg import TwoPoints ImportError: No module named msg
```

in my package.xml

```
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>message_generation</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>
 

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>visualization_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>

  <build_export_depend>geometry_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>visualization_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>sensor_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>sensor_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
```

my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(face_detection)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  cv_bridge
  geometry_msgs
  visualization_msgs
  message_generation
#  opencv2
)

add_message_files(
   FILES
   pt.msg
   TwoPoints.msg
)

generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   sensor_msgs
   visualization_msgs std_msgs geometry_msgs
)

catkin_package(
   CATKIN_DEPENDS
   message_runtime
)
```

I have tried lot of "solution" found,
e.g. roslib.load_manifest(), catkin_make install,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277706/importerror:-no-module-named-msg/) by [kookoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32932/kookoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-12-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is telling you that you don't have a module (folder) named `msg`. You need to change the `import` statement to reflect the name of the directory that your custom messages are stored in. For example, if your package's directory structure looked like this

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── launch
│   └── face_detection.launch
├── my_messages
│   ├── TwoPoints.msg
│   └── pt.msg
├── nodes
│   └── face_detection_node
├── package.xml
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── src
│   └── face_detection
│       └── face_detection_lib.py
```

As you can see, the custom messages are stored in the `my_messages` directory. So, your `import` statement would look like

```
from face_detection.my_messages import TwoPoints
```

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0